# Show answers that I previously upvoted at the top of the answers list

Tags: feature-request, answers, sorting

Months ago, I searched for an answer and found it on Stack Overflow.  I upvoted an answer way down the answers list.

Recently, I searched for the same thing.  I wasted time looking through the answers until I came to the one I had upvoted.  Sometimes, I upvote a different answer because it was more applicable.  So, I could have 2 or 3 upvoted answers.

Please sort my upvoted answers to the top of the answer list in order of total upvote score.  Then put the rest of the answers below.

Comment: I like this idea. If there's no interest in implementing it by Stack, it could make for a good user script :)

Comment: I'd say it *definitely* is unlikely to be implemented by SE anytime soon even if they notice, but it is, indeed, a nice idea

Comment: IMO this would be better as a search option (maybe even the default?) but it shouldn’t *replace* the existing function.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work, from what I can tell the search is not really a database search or something, it is more akin to an elasticsearch query (or maybe it is one). Sorting is going to be whatever Elastic or whatever tech is used is going to allow. A filter option ("upvoted: me", "downvoted:me" perhaps?) might be better doable.

Comment: @Gimby well, sorting can be done client-side, with a query to user's votes up/down done once per load. After all, the amount of information to transfer with each such request is ridiculously small even with avid voters